# Error: Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Window

Tags: selenium, appium-ios

I'm trying to set up Appium with Android Studio and encounter loads of errors. I include the necessary dependencies via Selenium and Appium jar file for java and use as a library, I get the following error:

Error: Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Window

Answer (score 0):

**Just add the following dependency in your app gradle. it is working fine for me **

```
implementation('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.41.0')
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
```